# Missing required parameter for [Route: X.update] in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following Edit and Update methods in my Laravel based application controller (`SampleTypeController.php`).

```
public function edit(sampletype $type) {
    return view('sampletypes.edit',compact('type'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\inventory  $inventory
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function update(Request $request, sampletype $type) {
    try {
        request()->validate([
            'samp_name' => 'required',
            'samp_desc' => 'required',
        ]);
        $type->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('sampletypes.index')
            ->with('success','Sample Type updated successfully');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('sampletypes.index')
            ->with('failed','An error occured.');
    }
}
```

And I have my route for the mentioned method like this in `web.php`,

```
Route::resource('sampletypes', SampleTypeController::class);
```

I already declared my controller at the top of my `web.php`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\SampleTypeController;
```

I can access the editing blade via my index blade, This is how I'm doing it

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Type Name</th>
        <th width="280px">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($sampletypes as $key => $sampletype)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $sampletype->samp_name }}</td>
            <td>
                @can('role-edit')
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('sampletypes.edit',$sampletype->id) }}">Edit</a>
                @endcan
                @can('role-delete')
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['sampletypes.destroy', $sampletype->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                @endcan
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

And my edit form in the blade looks like this,

```
{!! Form::model($type, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['sampletypes.update', $type->id]]) !!}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Type Name:</strong>
            {!! Form::text('samp_name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Type Name','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Type Description:</strong>
            {!! Form::text('samp_desc', null, array('placeholder' => 'Type Description','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But when I try to access my edit URL (`http://sample.test/sampletypes/1/edit`) it keeps giving me the following error

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: sampletypes.update] [URI: sampletypes/{sampletype}] [Missing parameter: sampletype]. (View: E:\MY_PROJECTS\jodulk\resources\views\sampletypes\edit.blade.php)
```

I'm struggling to find where and what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Try to dd $sampletypes from controller to verify if you are getting id. It is best practice to use first letter capital for modal like instead of sampletype you can you Sampletype or SampleType. I do personally prefer second one as its more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('sampletypes', SampleTypeController::class);
```

replace with this

```
Route::resource('sampletypes', App\Http\Controllers\SampleTypeController::class);
```

try this i hope you will got your solution .